# Add Default action in the route attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How to set default action using Route attribute

```
[Route("cars/[action]")]
public class CarsRegistrationController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    { ... }
}
```

cars/index works but if i go to /cars (without entering action name) i want it to redirect to default action index /cars/index

I tried modifying the Route to: no luck, How do I fix the syntax

```
[Route("cars/{action=index}")]
[Route("cars/[action:index]")]
```

Comment: What issue do you have when using `[Route("cars/{action=index}")]`? That appears to work for me.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I get error: Error: The attribute route 'cars/{action=index}' cannot contain a parameter named '{action}'. Use '[action]' in the route template to insert the value 'Index'. I also tried [Route("cars/[action=index]")] Error: While processing template 'cars/[action=index]', a replacement value for the token 'action=index' could not be found

Answer (score 5):

As you can read in the documentation of ASP.NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) putting a route on a controller means that it will combine with the routes on its actions.

```
[Route("[cars]")]
public class CarsRegistrationController : Controller
{
   [Route("~/cars")]   // Matches "~/cars"
   [Route("")]         // Matches "~/cars/Index"
   public IActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

Comment: please note, my controller name is 'CarsRegistrationController' but the route that i want to use is 'cars', can you modify your answer code to make it work with my corntoller,code, I cant make it work